# File downloading partially and I need entire file

Tags: php, header, http-headers

I have some files I am trying to download on my server through the use of headers. It finds the file, but its only downloading 200 to 300 kbs of these files when they are 2 to 3 MBs. I can't seem to put my finger on this one.

Here is my code.

I have an ob_start method at the beginning of the file FYI.

```
$fileName = $row['fileURL'];
$fileURL = 'powerpoints/' . $fileName;
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $fileName);
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($fileURL);
exit();
```

EDIT BELOW..MODIFIED CODE

```
$fileName = $row['fileURL'];
$fileURL = 'powerpoints/' . $fileName;
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $fileName);
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($row['size']));

$fdl = fopen($fileURL, "r"); 

if ($fdl === false) {
    die("Issue opening $fileURL");
}

while (!feof($fdl))
{
    $buffer = fread($fdl, 4096); 
    print $buffer;
}  

fclose($fdl);
```

Comment: Have you double-checked the output of filesize($file) for your Content-Length? If this is incorrect, or blank, it might terminate the download early. I don't see the $file variable specified in your code example.

Answer (score 0):

Readfile will try to read everything into memory at once. Also, I don't see the point of using output buffering here, when you have better chance of success by just reading and outputting the file in chunks.

So I would get rid of output buffering, and try something like this instead of readfile:

```
sleep(1);
$fdl = fopen($fileURL, 'r');
if ($fdl === false) {
  die("Issue opening $fileURL");
}
while(!feof($fdl)) {
  $buffer = fread($fdl, 4096);
  print $buffer;
}
fclose($fdl);
```

Additional note, why do you have `Pragma: public` when you have must-revalidate on cache control?

Comment: I followed this tutorial a while back on headers and I think this was in there. I got rid of it.

Comment: Well now its downloading 500 kb's instead of a few hundred.

Comment: @wowzuzz can you add your code now somewhere so it can be seen from

Comment: @wowzuzz ok, I don't see issues there... have you tested if the same problem occurs irrelevant of where you access the page from?

Comment: eis, thanks for your help. It ended up being the wrong path for the fileURL which was the problem <facepalm>

Thanks so much for your help.